# How to see what a use has chosen from a JList?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlist

Recently, I have been working on a Java Jukebox program. So far in this program, the user selects a song from a JList, and hits a "Play" JButton. What I need to do is have the program find out what choice was chosen from the list and then launch the corresponding constructor. Any suggestions on how to do that?

-John

Comment: Could you include the relevant code in your question please?

Comment: It's below. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `JList`'s `getSelected` methods, in particular `getSelectedValue()` and `getSelectedValues()`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`JList#getSelectedIndex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedIndex%28%29) and/or [`Jlist#getSelectedIndices`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedIndices%28%29) which will tell you what is currently selected.

And take a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details

Comment: That's strange. When I do that, all I get is "null" when I try to run it.

Comment: @AirTime Given the fact that we have no code to go on, it's impossible to know why

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
    package box.java.juke.airtime;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JList;
    import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

    public class JukeBox {
     public static final int WIDTH = 300;
     public static final int HEIGHT = 400;
     public static final String NAME = "Java JukeBox";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame j = new JFrame(NAME);
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    j.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    j.setVisible(true);
    j.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    String[] songs = { "Cipher", "Flight", "To the Stars",
            "Last Train to Paradise", "Surge" };
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    JList list = new JList(songs);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    j.add(list);
    System.out.println(list.getSelectedValue());
    JButton b = new JButton();
    b.setText("Play");
    j.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, b);
    j.setResizable(false);
}
```

}